# What does "unmount" mean in terms of partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, windows-10

I am dualbooting Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Both are running on the same hard drive, but on different partitions. When I am running Ubuntu I'm seeing my primary harddrive partition where the Windows OS is, in the Ubuntu launcher.

When I rightclick this, it gives me the option of "unlock from launcher" or "unmount". What would happen if I unmounted this partition (where Windows 10 reads and writes)? It wouldn't damage my dualboot setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unmount option will disconnect your Windows partition from Ubuntu.

It will not damage anything on that partition. It is 100% safe.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu handles drives somewhat differently from how Windows does. Ubuntu has various devices available to be read from/written to; you can see a good chunk of them by running `ls /dev` in Terminal.

Your drives (and their subsequent partitions) are accessible from a location assigned to them by the system, but it's usually something like `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sdb3`. While you can use these (and people do) it's a bit easier to remember what the partition or device is if it has a name to it.

Thus, the system will create a folder (usually in the `/media/USERNAME` directory) that allows you to access your files, and it will give it the label that the filesystem has for that partition or device. This is what is called *mounting a filesystem*. This will also prevent certain changes (like formatting the partition) from occurring.

Thus, when you tell Ubuntu to *unmount* the Windows filesystem, you're telling it to remove that `/media/USERNAME/FILESYSTEMNAMEHERE` link. It will also allow other things to be done to that filesystem if need be, but those aren't applicable to your question.

**TL;DR**: **No**, unmounting the Windows 10 partition will not harm the files in any way, shape, or form. You're simply disconnecting those files from being quickly accessible for the time being (while you're using Ubuntu). It is purely a software-level change and will not affect the physical disk itself.

If you're still curious, go ahead and read [this Q/A over on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3247/understanding-mount-as-a-concept-in-the-os). There are several very good explanations of what mounting/unmounting is and what it does in Linux.